# SYBASE BCP LOADING ERROR

Tags: database, sybase, bcp

When I am trying to load a bcp file following error is seen in the error file

"

## @ Batch starting at Row 1: Server Message: masterdataservice - Msg 4837, Level 16, State 1:

Bad row data received from the client while bulk copying into object 1488005301 partition 1488005301 in database 47. Received a row of length 1966 whilst maximum or expected row length is 1964.
@#

## @ Batch starting at Row 1: Not transferred @

"

Actual length of my bcp file is 1614 bytes only but it is showing in the error file as 1966.
When I am loading a bcp file with 1611 bytes data it is being loaded successfully.

Could anyone please tell me why this is occuring?

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Could be a hidden character issue?  Any mix of *nix and Windows in your data transfer?

Comment: if you are running on a unix server multiple ace versions make sure that LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH64 is set to the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the table lock schema.

If the table's lock scheme is of type "data pages" then it will allow only 1524 bytes data.

I have chnged the lock scheme to "lock pages" and tried to load the bcp file and it is loaded, because if the lock schema of the table is "lock pages" it can have 1964 bytes of data.